# Preg_match backtrack error

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

When I use the regex `(.*)*[0]` everything works well:

```
preg_match('/(.*)*[0]/', 'this is a test string');
var_dump(preg_last_error()); // no code's returned
```

But when I add another character to char class, it will throw out error:

```
preg_match('/(.*)*[01]/', 'this is a test string');
var_dump(preg_last_error()); // int(2)
```

Code #2 means `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR`. What an additional character can do here though?

Comment: What's the point of `(.*)*`? Won't it keep finding new empty strings infinitely?

Comment: @Cthulhu that's just kinda a test case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[When nesting repetition operators, make absolutely sure that there is only one way to match the same match.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: @stema: Yeah, I was rushed to complete that explanation.  I will let the link explain the details, as one paragraph isn't enough space to explain the concept.